# How does the scala REPL work when defining a class?

Tags: scala, read-eval-print-loop

If I open the Scala REPL, I noticed I can create classes.

My questions are:

- What does the REPL do when there is a class definition?
- Does it compile the class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The REPL is not an interpreter in the usual sense, as it never executes code directly. Code that you enter in the REPL is always compiled and so are class definitions.

Comment: So everything I write in the `scala` REPL it gets compiled. Something like: Read Compile Evaluate Print Loop :)

Comment: yeah but who can pronounce RCEPL?

Comment: Whether or not `eval` is implemented with a compiler or an interpreter is a private internal implementation detail of `eval`. `eval` is just `eval`, regardless of whether it is implemented as an interpreter or a compiler. In Scala, the REPL happens to be a thin wrapper around the compiler, but that is an implementation detail. You could just as well implement it as an interpreter.