# running scala classes on intellij ide and eclipse

Tags: scala, class, intellij-idea, ide

I have recently started programming with scala with an intellij ide . While running the worksheets with classes or traits I'm just getting defined class classname . The output of what is within the class is not visible. I'm running scala with sbt and java 8.I even tried running the same worksheet on eclipse still getting the same output

```
abstract class Base {
  def foo = 1

  def bar: Int
}

class Sub extends Base {

  def bar = 3
}

defined class Base

defined class Sub
```

Comment: Please post your code samples, or just use `case class` instead of `class` for better content-oriented output

Comment: Here done @Odomontois

Comment: And what other output are you expecting?

Comment: I'm expecting it to show bar=3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The worksheets in IDE work the same way as [Scala REPL](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/2097).

How does REPL work? It takes every expression or statement (typically a line), evaluates it and prints the value of the expression or side effects. If you define a class, the side effect is that the class is [compiled from Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12712334/2032064) to Java bytecode and available for use. REPL lets you know about this side effect with  `defined class Base`. If you put in an expression, it translates the expression from Scala to bytecode, evaluates it and prints the result.

If you put in

```
class Foo { println("x") }
```

you get `defined class Foo`. If you now put in

```
new Foo()
```

the worksheet will print `x` (a side effect of calling the constructor of `Foo`) and the value of expression `new Foo()`: `res0: Foo = Foo@64c8e9cd`. The `res0=` part notifies you about one thing that REPL did automatically - it assigned the expression to a new unique variable `res0` so that you can use it later on.

Now, why is it not possible to print `bar=3` as you expect? That means you are expecting the worksheet to print some kind of definition of the class to the output. That would mean translating the compiled Scala code back to Scala language, but there are many ways how to write the same class definition in Scala! It simply doesn't work this way and there is no point in repeating your class definition again in the output.